# What is the user that actually write on disk in Ruby? Write error

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, file-io, permissions

I have the following environment:

- I have an Ubuntu 10.10 server with `nginx`, `passenger`, `ruby 1.9.2`, `ror 3.*`, `postgresql` (`db` is not in the game here)
- I have an application that is on `/var/www/` (example folder)
- My rack user is `www-data` (`nginx` user as well)

  > www-data 21977  0.1  7.2  53324 44420 ?        Sl   Dec01   2:21 Rack: /var/www/
  >      www-data  1187  0.0  0.4  10620  2468 ?        S    Nov24   2:47 nginx: worker process
- My folder `/var/www/public` belongs to `www-data` and is in `755`

  > drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 2011-12-02 16:13 public

And I get the following error (relevant parts):

```
Errno::EACCES in AnswerLinesController#export_csv
Permission denied - public/survey_70_result_csv.csv
app/controllers/answer_lines_controller.rb:647:in `initialize'
app/controllers/answer_lines_controller.rb:647:in `open'
app/controllers/answer_lines_controller.rb:647:in `export_csv'
```

I then turn my folder `/public` to `775`, same result.
I then turn my folder `/public` to `777`, working!
For the fun, I try to turn my folder `/public` to `755` again. It's working.

1. How is Ruby (or Ruby On Rails?) actually managing the rights/permissions?
2. Is there any kind of permissions or write caching?
3. Who is the actual user writing on the disk? Ruby's user? (In that case, `www-data`?)
4. How to explain the fact that first it doesn't work in `755`, then it works in `777`, then it finally works in `755`? Who is causing the trouble? The filesystem layer or Ruby's write-to-disk module that would be confused?

Or is it a bug in Ruby?

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions on `survey_70_result_csv.csv` when you manage to create it?

Comment: Mu, that's a good question, here is the answer:    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 7962 2011-12-03 02:59 survey_70_result_csv.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not Ruby nor Rails that is managing the permissions. It is Passenger.
   Basically, it depends on how you have configured passenger. If it uses the user switching (which I think is the default), then it will run under the user who own the file `config/environment.rb` (for Rails apps) or `config.ru` (for Rack apps), unless that have been overridden in the config.
   You can read more about it on http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#user_switching
2. Not that I am aware of, there might be write caching in the filesystem, but none that should affect the permissions in this case.
3. See number one.
4. Well, this is my guess: Did you remove the file before trying again? Or did you change the filename? If not then according to my understanding on how it works, the file will already have the same owner that is trying to write to it, which means that the process can do whatever it wants with the file. The actual permissions of the directory doesn't matter as long as the process have permissions to write to the file.

(one example is for instance if you remove the read permission of a directory, but keep it for the file, the user won't be able to list the files in the directory, but if he knows the complete filename, he will still be able to access the file)

Comment: I think (4) is the key question; AFAIK, overwriting an existing file merely requires write access to the file but creating it requires write access to the directory.

Comment: Ah that is very interesting. Thanks Jimmy. To reply to the point number 4, I think you might be right. I actually did delete the file, but I then tried to recreate the very same one. Which was successful. I then tried - just now - to create another file and it has not been working with 755 permissions. But it has been working with the 777 permissions. I think we're through. I'll have a look at your link for the user switching and will post back here if any new info on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Jimmy was right on the user_switching. It was basically a user permission problem ( as I thought ) but couldn't get the finger on it.

The thing is:

**From [Phusion-Passenger documentation](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerDefaultUser) about the default user value: "The default value is nobody."**

Which explains why I had to set my public/ folder access to 777 and 775 wasn't working.

I modified my nginx configuration by adding in the server { } block:

```
    passenger_user www-data;
```

Then restarted the whole thing, set back my public/ folder rights to 755 and then everything worked fine.